# Using an ES6 module with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, requirejs

I have code like this that I need to put in a legacy project that uses RequireJS.  I have tried to use Babel but I don't actually need the entire class transpiled to ES5, I just need it to be AMD RequireJS style.

Is there a recommended tool to convert ES6 modules like this or should I just rewrite them by hand?  I don't know how to rewrite the following for RequireJS.

```
import CanvasTile from './maputil.js';
export default class MapView {
    constructor(opts) {
        //create map
    }
    async getImage(sceneId, url, hasOvr = true) {} 
}
```

The .babelrc I tried was

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
}
```

Comment: ... why? Don't forget that despite all the bundling, you're still _just creating a web page_, so just import the module on its own with a normal `<script src="./js/maputil.js" type="module" async></script>` tag, instead of forcing it into your bundle, and then access it via `window`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using https://babeljs.io/repl with the plugin "babel-plugin-transform-modules-requirejs v0.1.4" to help figure out how to get the above working in RequireJS.